# Xcode 5 quits unexpectedly right after I try to Downloading Identities

Tags: ios, crash, ios7, xcode5, xcode-organizer

For some reason with the new Xcode 5, after I 'Validate' my app in the Organizer and attempt to download the identities by connecting to the iOS Dev Center through the organizer, the app closes. A message comes up saying that Xcode has closed unexpectedly. Please help! I feel like I've tried everything.

Comment: The profile you are using same as you were using before upgrading Xcode5?

Comment: So you want to validate your app for app store and it is not validating? Is this your problem?

Comment: @Manthan, correct. I'm trying to upload the iOS7 version of my app onto iTunes Connect and connect. I was trying to do it through Xcode by Validating it and then Distributing the app.

Comment: Have same problem... Did you solved it?

Answer (score 6):

You need to refresh certs/prov profiles via XCode > Preferences > Accounts

XCode > Preferences > Accounts > Click on your DEV ACCOUNT > View Details button (bottom right) > Signing Iden/PPs screen appears > hit Refresh.

If error appears saying "no cert found" make sure you chose your dev account.

My email account is ADMIN status. I had clicked on the AGENT one by accident and when I hit refresh it said NO CERTS would I like to refresh. DONT!!

yes XCode crashes if you update PPs on developer.apple.com and then try and Validate in Xcode > Organizer

Comment: This is what help for me. I had a certificate which had been revoked and another recreated and I had to refresh within the Preferences > Accounts for it to pick up the changes to the certificates.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me:

- Revoked my existing certificates (this was probably not necessary)
- Had Xcode generate new certificates with Preferences > Accounts > View Details > Reload arrow (this was probably only necessary because I revoked)
- Visited http://developer.apple.com > iOS Dev Center > Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > Provisioning Profiles
- Clicked + and added a new App Store provisioning profile
- Downloaded the resulting profile and opened it (launches Xcode)

With this new profile, I'm no longer prompted that I have no identities. I've just submitted an app to the App Store with the new provisioning profile. Wish me luck!

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a New Provisioning Profile for distribution to fix it.

Make a new profile and clean and build your code again and Validate it again.

It should work fine.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I think you will have to delete the certificate also associated with this. You need to recreate it all again.

Comment: Try using safari instead of firefox. Create a new profile with it. It may work.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue. I don't know how to fix it, but I have found a way to avoid this crash. Use Application Loader utility instead of Xcode uploading directly.

[image]

Comment: well - how do you create an archive from it?